# ASP.NET / C#: Run command at specific interval

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have an auction site coded using SinglarR, and MVC5.I have a credit card token stored in my database for every single bidder. At the end of the auction, the winning bidder's credit card needs to be charged.

What would be the most efficient way to accomplish this? I thought about using a filter, however, the code would only be ran the next time a visitor arrives, which might be a long period of time on some days

Comment: The payment should be deducted right after the auction is completed or that item is marked as sold to the buyer or when the buyer logs into the system next time?

Comment: As soon as the auction ends.

Comment: It is worth noting that you should not be storing your user's credit card details at all. Instead, you should rely on a payment service.

Comment: credit card token, as stated in the original post.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need a scheduled task. It can be done with HttpModule. Implement something like:

```
public class CheckAuctionsScheduleModule : IHttpModule
{
    static Timer timer;
    long interval = 60000; //60 secs
    static object synclock = new object();
    public void Init(HttpApplication app)
    {
        if(timer==null) timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(CheckAuctions), null, 0, interval);
    }

    private void CheckAuctions(object obj)
    {
        lock (synclock)
        {
           //implement here your logic
           //check completed auctions
           //send notifications to bidder etc.  

        }
    }
    public void Dispose()
    { 
    //implement if needed
    }
}
```

In your web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <add name="CheckAuctionsSchedule" type="MyMvcApp.Modules.CheckAuctionsScheduleModule"/>
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Note: Module works as long as MVC application running. There are other solutions for scheduled tasks(as microsoft recommends win services). [This](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx) can be useful.

Comment: how do you identify this scheduler is working for which auction???
If we have multiple auctions does this mean it will be running parallel for each auction?