# need to call an web service in a specific time with c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created an email function in web service, I need to call the function and sent the email out everyday in 18.30. How do I able to detect the time of my current system and call the web service according to the time. I have tried the infinite loop method to compare the time, it works but somehow I think it is not a correct way.

```
while (1 == 1)
        {

            DateTime dtNowTime = DateTime.Now;
            if (dtNowTime.Hour == 18 && dtNowTime.Minute == 30)
            {

                int status = 0;
                status = sending.HelloWorld();
                if (status == 1)
                {
                    Response.Write("<script>alert('Success');</script>");
                }
                else
                {

                    Response.Write("<script>alert('Fail');</script>");
                }

            }

        }
```

This is the method I tried so far, is that a better way to achieve this?

Comment: You can try HttpModule - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29787600/asp-net-c-run-command-at-specific-interval/29789337#29789337

Comment: Good way is to write the `windows service` which will trigger the email send on time basis or create a `scheduler` using timer to do the work. Here is way to create [the scheduler](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/application-scheduler-service-using-C-Sharp-net-and-xml/).

Comment: check if your hosting provider provide any scheduler like azure websites provide scheduler facility.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YbCvQeXpcQY I use Quartz.NET demo by this gentleman. Can someone with experience with Quartz.NET help me to change this   .WithCronSchedule("0 0/1 * * * ?")  which is fire the emailjob every minute into fire the emailjob at 18.30 everyday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the best way to achieve what you are looking for. In my opinion you should either create a job in SQL Server management studio that send email or use library like Quartz.NET which keeps jobs schedule and run on provided time. There is another way of doing this my keeping global cache or something similar in global configuration file. Try either SQL job or Quartz.NET

Comment: Thank you, sir. Done it with the Quartz.NET

Answer (score 0):

Other way around you can create a console application and run it using built-in Windows Task scheduler and schedule it to run every 18:30.

For more info in how to create a task:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/manas1/console-application-using-windows-scheduler/